# How to autoload from root namespace?

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

Trying the following config to load my models from root namespace failed. any alternative?

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "\\": "app/Models"
    }
  },
```

The following works but I have to run `dumpautoload` each time I create a new class.

```
"classmap": [
      "app/Models"
    ],
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `"\\"`, you should map `""` to `"app/Models"`. Quoting from [composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4):

> If you want to have a fallback directory where any namespace will be
>   looked for, you can use an empty prefix like:
>
> ```
> {
>     "autoload": {
>         "psr-4": { "": "src/" }
>     }
> }
> ```

So, in your case:

```
{ 
   "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
          "": "app/Models"
        }
     }
}
```